# SignalR PersistentConnection fails to call client callback method 40-50% of the time on Azure

Tags: jquery, asp.net, azure, signalr, signalr.client

BACKGROUND INFO:  I'm using MVC 4.  I'm calling a PersistentConnection SignalR method on the Server and delaying it for 20 seconds before it calls back to the client callback method.  Within the callback method, I'm setting the url to the download method within the MVC controller so that it initiates a file stream download.

THE PROBLEM:  This all works perfectly fine with a locally hosted website on IIS 7.5, but it's very inconsistent when I deploy to the Azure cloud.  I've done 10 test-runs on both Chrome and IE 10:  On Chrome, the download fails to kick-in 40% of the time and on IE 10 the download doesn't occur 50% of the time.  So what's happening is that the callback method is not being called 40-50% of the time.  I know this to be the case since I put JavaScript code in there to print the current time to the page, and that doesn't fire as well.  Here are some screenshots of the network traffic on Chrome and IE 10:

Chrome Success:
[image]

Chrome Failure:
[image]

IE 10 Success:
[image]

IE 10 Failure:
[image]

I really need for the SignalR callbacks to the client to be 100% effective using Azure before I can use this library.  Is this a known bug with SignalR or is there a different approach to using this signalr for Windows Azure?

Here is my code:

SERVER:

```
   public class MultiFileConnection : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
            return Connection.Send(connectionId, data);

        }
    }
```

CLIENT:

```
$('#dBtn').click(function () {

    var docIds = sceneLayoutService.getSelection();
    var href;
    var docIdsParam;

    if (docIds.length === 0) {
        alert("you need to select one");
        return false;
    }
    else if (docIds.length == 1) {
        docIdsParam = "docId=" + docIds;

        href = window.baseUrl;
        var today = new Date();

        // Initialize SignalR connection
        var connection = $.connection(href + "/multifile");

        $("#test-signalr").append("<li>" + today + "</li>");

        // SignalR callback method by server
        connection.received(function (data) {
            today = new Date();
            $("#test-signalr").append("<li>" + today + "</li>");
            connection.stop();
            href = window.baseUrl + '/CloudStorage/Download?' + docIdsParam;
            window.location.href = href;
        });

        // SignalR send data to the server
        connection.start()
            .done(function () {
                connection.send("you need to select one!!");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("Error connecting to signalr realtime service");
            });
    }
    else {
        docIdsParam = jQuery.param(docIds.map(function (value) {
            return { "name": "docIds", "value": value };
        }));
        href = window.baseUrl + '/CloudStorage/DownloadZip?' + docIdsParam;
    }
    return true;
});
```

LIST OF PACKAGES:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Company.CONNECT.Analytics.eFWrapper" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Company.CONNECT.Analytics.Logging" version="1.0.0.11" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Company.CONNECT.Web" version="1.1.0.12" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="2.5.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Castle.Core-log4net" version="2.5.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="2.5.4" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor-log4net" version="2.5.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Common" version="5.0.505.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Configuration" version="5.0.1118.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="4.1.10331.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.6" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.10.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery.vsdoc" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="log4net" version="1.2.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers" version="1.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel" version="6.1.7600.16394" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="2.0.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="RequireJS" version="2.1.8" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="SevenZipSharp" version="0.64" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="SlowCheetah" version="2.5.5" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.5.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="System.Web.Providers" version="1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Unity" version="2.1.505.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Unity.Interception" version="2.1.505.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="2.0.5.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="2.0.6.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Do you have more than one machine? If you do, read this http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: I'll have to check into this.  So you're saying that some of the messages being sent from the server are most likely being lost because there's 2 or more servers being used within Azure (in our case)?

Comment: I have a theory.  Please let me know if I'm off the mark since I'm pretty new to all of this.  If there are two servers in the Azure farm, that means there are two instances of my web app.  The client is connecting to ONE of those instances and sending in the client id as well as the message.  The Azure Load Balancer then chooses one of the instances to respond back to the client (so it's like the flip of a coin which one responds).  If the one not connected to the client responds, then it fails.  Otherwise, the correct instance responding succeeds.  Am I in the ballpark?

Comment: Second question:  If my company has Azure scaled out to more than one server, is the only solution to setup a backplane even though I only need to send back to the calling client?

Comment: Yes, especially on azure where you don't control the load balancer.

Comment: Much appreciated, as usual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Fowler, from the above comments, pointed me in the right direction.  It turns out there are 2 Web Role instances running in my Windows Azure configuration.  When there are multiple Azure instances running, a "backplane" needs to be used since we have no control over which instance the Azure Load Balancer chooses.  This is why the messages sent back from the server to client were failing 50% of the time.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr (new versions)

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/older-versions/scaleout-in-signalr (signalR 1.1)